# Repeatedly update a list in the ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I'm using the Estimote SDK for Android. I'm trying to change the provided code on the official site. I want to show the list of the detected beacons in a ListFragment (with some information for each Beacon).

In my main Activity i start all the necessary (service, listeners..), and in particular i have this onCreate(...) method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
           // update the list of the beacons in the ListFragment in some way
        }
    });
}
```

If i understood correctly, this method is called continuosly every fixed time.

This is the code of the ListFragment:

```
public class DiscoveredBeacons extends ListFragment {

    private List<Beacon> beacons = new ArrayList<Beacon>();
    private Beacon beacon;
    private View mContentView = null;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        this.setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.beacon_row, beacons));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacons_list, null);
        return mContentView;
    }

    // this does not work if i call it from the main Activity
    public void updateList(List<Beacon> beacons) {
        beacons.clear();
        beacons.addAll(beacons);
        ((MyListAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Beacon> {

        private List<Beacon> items;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                               List<Beacon> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)  getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.beacon_row, null);
            }
            Beacon beacon = items.get(position);
            if (beacon != null) {
                TextView number = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.number);
                TextView rssi = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rssi);
                TextView power = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.power);
                TextView distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distance);
                if(number != null) {
                    number.setText("Beacon number " + (position + 1));
                }
                if (rssi != null) {
                    rssi.setText("rssi: " + beacon.getRssi()); // int
                }
                if (power != null) {
                    power.setText("power: " + beacon.getMeasuredPower()); // int
                }
                if(distance != null) {
                    distance.setText("distance: " + Utils.computeAccuracy(beacon));
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, i tried to put a public method in the ListFragment, and call it the listener inside the onCreate, but this doesn't work. In particular i get an exception:

04-01 20:14:04.029  18052-18052/it.loris.beaconsdetector E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: it.loris.beaconsdetector, PID: 18052
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
            at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.clear(Collections.java:936)
            at it.loris.beaconsdetector.DiscoveredBeacons.updateList(DiscoveredBeacons.java:40)
            at it.loris.beaconsdetector.BeaconsDetector$1.onBeaconsDiscovered(BeaconsDetector.java:41)
            at com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager$IncomingHandler.handleMessage(BeaconManager.java:479)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an easy mistake. You are trying to clear a List of Beacons, but not your list, the list instance you receive from the method. Use "this" to access your beacon in your list fragment. and add the beacons you receive from the method. this should fix it.

```
// this does not work if i call it from the main Activity
public void updateList(List<Beacon> beacons) {
    // Call this to refer your variable in List fragment
    this.beacons.clear();
    this.beacons.addAll(beacons);
    ((MyListAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Ok, it is incredible -.- Now it is ok. Just  a question. Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: @user3075478 Correct way to do what ? update the list of items in your list fragment ?

Comment: you have two list of Beacons, `List<Beacon> beacons`. I would reduce it to one list. You can remove the one in your list fragment and use the one inside your ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @user3075478 np, you can try upvoting the answer you think it's useful and it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to **getView()**

```
if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)  getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.beacon_row, null);
        } else { v = convertView; }
```